# Can’t unlock MacBook Air with PIN from Find my iPhone

Tags: unlock, find-my-mac

I locked my MacBook Air through Find My iPhone app because I thought I had lost it. One day later I found it. I tried to unlock it with the PIN I had set and apparently I remembered the PIN wrong.

I logged into iCloud from another PC and got my PIN right. When I tried to insert it again it wasn’t possible. In the screen I could only see **Wrong Passcode. Try Again.** There is no place where I can insert the passcode. If I restart it, it says that my device is disabled and I have to wait 60 min. After 60 min, same message **Wrong Passcode. Try Again.** and no place where to insert passcode.

I tried what other people suggested in similar posts (option+cmd+R) and it didn’t work for me.

How do I resolve the issue?